# Can I use android.mk in android p? I got ninja: error: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-xxxx'

Tags: android, makefile, ninja

I am porting my android-m code into android-p. I want to use the old android.mk directly. But When I use mm in the project folder, it gives me unknown target 'MODULES-IN-vendor-mycompany-packages-mylib-xxx' error.

The folder is in vendor/mycompany/packages/mylib/xxx.

Comment: I am also having this issue. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to /Android.bp

optional_subdirs = [
...,
"vendor/mycompany/packages/*/*"
]